# обновление DataGridView WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, есть метод с биндингом и привязкой таблиц к гриду

```
public void GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                cs = new ConnectionString();
                var loadData = cs.LoadFile("DataConnection.xml");
                string connString = String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User Id={2};Password={3}", loadData.Host, loadData.Database, loadData.UserId, loadData.PWD);
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString);

                // Create a DataSet.
                data = new DataSet();
                data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                // Add data from the BTA_USERS table to the DataSet.
                //string strUsersData = String.Format("select * from BTA_USERS where \"ID\" != {0} and \"isDelUser\" is null", loadData.LastId);
                string strUsersData = String.Format("select 1 isSystem, 0 ID, 'Система' Пользователь, 1 Online, '' Непрочитанные union " +
                                                    "select 0 isSystem, BTA_USERS.\"ID\", \"NAME\", " +
                                                    "case when BTA_USERS_ENTEREXIT.\"id\" is not null then '1' else '0' end as Online," +
                                                    "qqq = (select count(*) " +
                                                    "from sta_Messages " +
                                                    "where \"GetDate\" is null and \"GetUser_id\" = {0} and \"SetUser_id\" = BTA_USERS.\"ID\") " +
                                                    "from BTA_USERS " +
                                                    "left join BTA_USERS_ENTEREXIT on BTA_USERS.\"ID\" = BTA_USERS_ENTEREXIT.\"user_id\" " +
                                                    "and cast(convert(char(8), BTA_USERS_ENTEREXIT.\"date_enter\", 112) as datetime) = cast(convert(char(8), GETDATE(), 112) as datetime) " +
                                                    "and BTA_USERS_ENTEREXIT.\"date_exit\" is null " +
                                                    "where BTA_USERS.\"ID\" != {0} and BTA_USERS.\"isDelUser\" is null " +
                                                    "order by 1 desc, 3 asc, 2 asc", loadData.LastId);
                SqlDataAdapter usersDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strUsersData, connection);
                usersDataAdapter.Fill(data, "BTA_USERS");

                // Add data from the sta_Messages table to the DataSet.
                string strPostData = String.Format("select \"id\", \"GetText\" Сообщение, " +
                                                    "case when \"SetUser_id\" = {0} then \"GetUser_id\" else \"SetUser_id\" end as Sender, " +
                                                    "case when \"SetUser_id\" = {0} then 'исходящее' else 'входящее' end as Stream " +
                                                    "from sta_Messages " +
                                                    "where \"SetUser_id\" = {0} or \"GetUser_id\" = {0}", loadData.LastId);
                SqlDataAdapter postsDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strPostData, connection);
                postsDataAdapter.Fill(data, "sta_Messages");

                //// Establish a relationship between the two tables.
                DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("UsersMessages",
                    data.Tables["BTA_USERS"].Columns["ID"],
                    data.Tables["sta_Messages"].Columns["Sender"]);
                data.Relations.Add(relation);

                // Bind the master data connector to the BTA_USERS table.
                BindingSource usersBindingSource = new BindingSource();
                BindingSource postsBindingSource = new BindingSource();
                usersBindingSource.DataSource = data;
                usersBindingSource.DataMember = "BTA_USERS";

                postsBindingSource.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
                postsBindingSource.DataMember = "UsersMessages";

                usersDataGridView.DataSource = usersBindingSource;
                postsDataGridView.DataSource = postsBindingSource;

                var usersTable = data.Tables["BTA_USERS"];                                                                        
                var statusColumn = usersTable.Columns.Add("В Системе", typeof(Icon));                                             
                foreach (DataRow row in usersTable.Rows)                                                            
                {
                    if ((int)row["Online"] == 1)
                        row["В Системе"] = Properties.Resources.greenround;
                    else
                        row["В Системе"] = Properties.Resources.redround;
                }
                //usersTable.Columns["Online"].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;
                usersTable.Columns.Remove("Online");

                var messageTable = data.Tables["sta_Messages"];
                var statusColumn3 = messageTable.Columns.Add("Направление", typeof(Icon));               
                foreach (DataRow row in messageTable.Rows)                                  
                {
                    if ((string)row["Stream"] == "исходящее")
                        row["Направление"] = Properties.Resources.Arrow_red;
                    else
                        row["Направление"] = Properties.Resources.Arrow_green;
                }
                messageTable.Columns.Remove("Stream");


                var statusColumn2 = messageTable.Columns.Add("Файл", typeof(Icon));
                foreach (DataRow row in messageTable.Rows)
                {

                    if (DBNull.Value.Equals(row["Сообщения"]))                                                       
                        row["Файл"] = Properties.Resources.document;
                    else
                        row["Файл"] = Properties.Resources.bullet_white;
                }

                usersDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                usersDataGridView.Columns[1].Visible = false;
                postsDataGridView.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                postsDataGridView.Columns[2].Visible = false;
                postsDataGridView.Columns[3].DisplayIndex = 1;
                postsDataGridView.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
                postsDataGridView.Columns[4].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Сообщение невозможно отобразить");
            }
        }
```

Задача такова, на другой форме я меняю пользователя и нужно чтобы на главной форме обновились гриды с данными под нового пользователя.

```
private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NewConnectionString();
            Form1 f = new Form1();
            f.ShowDialog();
            f.GetData();           
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
```

Данные затягиваются вроде как корректно, но гриды не обновляются. Пробовал и `Refresh()`. 
Если вызывать второе окно

```
private void okBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                NewConnectionString();
                Form1 f = new Form1();
                f.Show();
                f.GetData();           
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
```

то на новом окне уже отображается обновленный грид, но старое окно тоже висит.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Из вашего кода невозможно понять логику изменения пользователя. Если был пользователь Вася, а потом стал пользователь Петя, то после выбора Пети его имя по идее должно передаваться в ваш метод `GetData()` в качестве параметра, кот. затем участвовал бы в запросе к БД, чтоб получить петины данные.

Comment: при выборе пользователя вытягивается имя и его id и записываются в файл. В методе `GetData()` в запросе в качестве параметра вытягивается айдишник пользователя. При смене пользователя, файл перезаписывается данными под последним пользователем. Вроде как после смены пользователя, мы повторно вызываем метод `GetData()`, который уже должен перерисовывать гриды под нового юзера